# Mapping of icon to Menuitem creating li inside li using Material ui react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on material UI react on Menu component. I have mapped icon to menuitem, which in turn creates `li` because of which alignment is going for Toss. And also i would like to map Typography along with Icon & Text. Any help would be of great. Thanks . Below is my code. tried only for 1st row.

```
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import MenuList from '@mui/material/MenuList';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import ContentCut from '@mui/icons-material/ContentCut';
import ContentCopy from '@mui/icons-material/ContentCopy';
import ContentPaste from '@mui/icons-material/ContentPaste';
import Cloud from '@mui/icons-material/Cloud';

export const IconMenu = ({menuicons}) => {
  return (
    <Paper sx={{ width: 320, maxWidth: '100%' }}>
      <MenuList>
        <MenuItem>
                {menuicons.map(item => (
                    <ListItem>
                        <ListItemIcon>{item.icon}</ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText>{item.label}</ListItemText>
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
                <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                    ⌘X
                </Typography>
            </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <ContentCopy fontSize="small" />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText>Copy</ListItemText>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
            ⌘C
          </Typography>
        </MenuItem>        
        <Divider />
        <MenuItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Cloud fontSize="small" />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText>Web Clipboard</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>
      </MenuList>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

**Stories.js**

```
 menuicons: [{ icon: <ContentCut fontSize="small" />, label: "Cut", path: '/' }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need just to put the `Typography` inside the `map()`

```
<MenuItem>
  {menuicons.map((item) => (
    <ListItem>
      <ListItemIcon>{item.icon}</ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText>{item.label}</ListItemText>
      <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
        ⌘X
      </Typography>
    </ListItem>
  ))}
</MenuItem>
```